# Hide Standard Tabs from Netsuite Dashboard

Tags: javascript, cloud, netsuite, dashboard, erp

Is there a way to Hide the standard Tabs in Dashboard for particular role? Is there a setup level change involved in Netsuite?

Standard tabs like Document, Setup etc.,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the Role's *Center* is what determines the tabs that are displayed. You can build custom Centers (*Customization* > *Centers and Tabs* > *Centers*), then create new Roles, and assign the Roles to the appropriate custom Center.

Be careful, though: ***You cannot change a Role's Center once it has been set***

Comment: Yes, Iam using a Custom role with least permissions a role can have, but still i found Standard tabs like Document, Support, Setup are not disabled, is there a way to disable them?

Thanks